# Multi-Data of K-means and SVM

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cluster-computing, svm, k-means

I generate the multi data from mvnrnd. I could like use the K-means to clustering those data with 2 groups.And also want to know the accuracy of K-means,but i didn't know how to calculate that.How did i know the correct of k-means cluster to compare with the result and get the accuracy ?!

I have a multi data and the class , i know i could do the SVM. However,the accuracy of SVM was too low about 72% to 83%. I might have done some mistakes. I would like to hear some feedback. Thanks

```
 n=1;mu1=[0,0,0];mu2=[1,1,1]; mu3=[2,2,2]; mu4=[3,3,3]; m=0.9;s=[1 m m ;m 1 m ; m m 1];
data1 = mvnrnd(mu1,s,1000); data2 = mvnrnd(mu2,s,1000);data3 = mvnrnd(mu3,s,1000);data4 = mvnrnd(mu4,s,1000);
all_data = [data1;data2;data3;data4];
[idx,ctrs,sumD,D] = kmeans(all_data,2,'distance','sqE','start','sample');
model = svmtrain(idx,all_data);
mu7=[0,0,0];mu8=[1,1,1];mu9=[2,2,2];mu10=[3,3,3];
data7=mvnrnd(mu7,s,1000);data8=mvnrnd(mu8,s,1000);data9=mvnrnd(mu9,s,1000);data10=mvnrnd(mu10,s,1000);
test_data = [data7;data8;data9;data10]; value = svmpredict(idx,test_data,model);
```

I want to know where my mistakes or something wrong of my code. I don't know why my accuracy is so low.I really want to improve my code. Thanks !!

Comment: The most probable cause of your inaccuracy is the initial cluster centres.  You may have points belonging in other cluster memberships when they should belong to another cluster.  Try running `kmeans` a bunch of times then find what the average classification is before throwing it into your SVM.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate accuracy of k-means algorithm You should have an a priori knowledge i.e. the reference class vector, like You have in SVM. 
Despite that the k-means is unsupervised learning algorithm and You don't need to have class vector to classify the data, You need it to calculate the accuracy. 
I have doubts for the method that You calculate model of the SVM as well. You use the indexes calculated from k-means algorithm witch has its own accuracy (right now it is not known). You use the modelled data for classification, so why won't you create your vector with classes?